# Issue with facebook android app integration

Tags: facebook

I am posting image to facebook using android app. On the facebook page, there appears a link with name of my app just above the image posted. How to add a url to this link ? Rightnow, if we click this link, it says page not available.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a website or canvas page URL in your app settings.

Comment: wouldnt this be loaded inside facebook itself ? how to make it open say google home page ?

Comment: No, a website URL would not be loaded inside Facebook.

Comment: if u use instagram and upload a photo, then if u click the link it takes you to instagram home page. how is that done ?